# From QUBO problem to quantum circuit

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, quantum-circuit

Can you describe how to convert some QUBO problem $$f(x_1, ..., x_n) = \sum\limits_{1 \le i < j \le n} \alpha_{i,j} \, x_i \, x_j$$ into its equivalent quantum circuits? Is it preferrable to start with the Ising formulation of the same problem (whose conversion from QUBO is explained [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11663/how-to-convert-qubo-problem-to-ising-hamiltonian))?